# "2SXC App" Dotnetnuke Crashes ONE Portal only

Tags: 2sxc, dotnetnuke-settings

I have somehow ended with a corrupt "2SXC App" in one of my Portals...

All the other Portals work fine but in this one portal as soon as I add a "2SXC App" and try and use the "blueImp" Gallery, the page crashes with an error... 
My question is... Is there way to repair this one portal? I have tried disabling and re-enabling the 2SXC App and Content modules but that did not fix the problem... Ideas PLEASE? Here is the error...

```
Error: ToSic.SexyContent.SexyContentException:
The template file '/Portals/1/2sxc/blueimp Gallery/_Gallery Tiles with Lightbox.cshtml' does not exist. at ToSic.SexyContent.Engines.EngineBase.Init(Template template, App app, ModuleInfo hostingModule, IDataSource dataSource, InstancePurposes instancePurposes, SxcInstance sexy) 
in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\SexyContent\Engines\EngineBase.cs:line 40 at ToSic.SexyContent.SxcInstance.GetRenderingEngine(InstancePurposes renderingPurpose) 
in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\SexyContent\SxcInstance.cs:line 244 at ToSic.SexyContent.SxcInstance.Render() 
in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\SexyContent\SxcInstance.cs:line 202
```

Answer (score 1):

you can see form the error that you are missing this file:
/Portals/1/2sxc/blueimp Gallery/_Gallery Tiles with Lightbox.cshtml

if you have blue imp installed in another portal then go to that file and copy it into the same directory in the original portal.